# Calling NtQuerydirectoryFile from a Kernel Hook Crashes the Kernel

Tags: c++, hook, drivers, windows-kernel, easyhook

I'm using the latest version of EasyHook to hook some kernel functions.
I did setup a debugging important successfully on a Windows 8.1 64-bit based virtual machine, and I tested hooking both of NtQuerydirectoryFile and NtQuerySystemInformation in user mode and NtQuerySystemInformation in kernel mode without any problem.

My current problem is hooking NtQuerydirectoryFile using the same code that I used for the user mode hook, but it fails when I call the original function giving me an access violation error. I'm using the following code for the kernel mode hook:

```
NTSTATUS NtQueryDirectoryFile_Hook(
    __in HANDLE FileHandle,
    __in_opt HANDLE Event,
    __in_opt PIO_APC_ROUTINE ApcRoutine,
    __in_opt PVOID ApcContext,
    __out PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    __out_bcount(Length) PVOID FileInformation,
    __in ULONG Length,
    __in FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass,
    __in BOOLEAN ReturnSingleEntry,
    __in PUNICODE_STRING FileName OPTIONAL,
    __in BOOLEAN RestartScan
    )
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    status = NtQueryDirectoryFile(FileHandle, Event, ApcRoutine, ApcContext, IoStatusBlock, FileInformation, Length, FileInformationClass, ReturnSingleEntry, FileName, RestartScan);
    return status;
}
```

Comment: And here's the dump:
http://pastebin.com/Y29dsRUQ

Comment: it looks like the BuildQueryDirectoryIrp function expects some kind of parameter in the RAX register, and due to the way the trampoline jump was implemented, the RAX register data is lost!
So I'm replacing this:

`48 b8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  mov rax, 0x0
ff e0                          jmp rax`

with this:
`50         push   rax
48 b8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  mov rax, 0x0
48 87 04 24                    xchg   QWORD PTR [rsp],rax
c3                        ret`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned before, the original trampoline jump modified the RAX register, so I replaced it with another trampoline:

```
50                             push   rax
48 b8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  mov rax, 0x0
48 87 04 24                    xchg   QWORD PTR [rsp],rax
c3                             ret
```

In addition to fixing the function that rely on hard-coded size of the trampoline jump code since the newer version is bigger. Now it's working without any problem.